# Inline plus operator in struct throws an exception (F#)

Tags: exception, struct, f#, operators

Why does the `fail` value throw an exception? `fine` value works. If I remove `inline` or if I convert `'t` into `float` then it works.

```
[<Struct>]
type Test<'t> =
  val x: 't
  val y: 't
  new (x,y) = { x = x; y = y }

  static member inline (+) ((x,y), a: _ Test) = 0
  static member inline (-) ((x,y), a: _ Test) = 0

let a = 1.,2.
let b = Test(1.,2.)
let fine = a - b
let fail = a + b
```

error message:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer fo
>   r 'AdditionDynamicImplTable`3' threw an exception. ---> System.NotSupportedExcep
>   tion: Dynamic invocation of op_Addition involving coercions is not supported.
>      at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.dyn@2445[a,b,c](Type aty, Type bt
>   y, Unit unitVar0)
>      at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.AdditionDynamicImplTable`3..cctor
>   ()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.AdditionDynamic[T1,T2,TResult](T1
>    x, T2 y)
>      at .$Program.main@() in C:\Users\olsv\Docume
>   nts\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.
>   fs:line 14
>   Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the compiler - or I am missing something (please report it at `fsbugs` at `microsoft` dot `com`). For some reason, the compiler fails to inline the call to the `+` operator (it seems to work for `-` and `/` and for custom operators like `+.`, but fails for `+` and `*`).

This means that the compiler actually generates something like:

```
// Inlined - returns zero directly
fine = 0; 

// Failed to inline - calls a version which used dynamic lookup
fail = LanguagePrimitives.AdditionDynamic
         <Tuple<double, double>, Test.Test<double>, double>(a, b);
```

The `AdditionDynamic` method uses some internal table to find an implementation of `+` for the two types at runtime. Although you could register your type there, it would not really be useful, because the invocation would be slow.

I do not really have any nice workaround for this - if you need the operator only for some basic numeric types (`float`, `int`, etc.) then the easiest option might be to just avoid using `inline` here and define (an overloaded) operator for the specific types:

```
 static member (+) ((x:float,y:float), a: float Test) = x + y + a.x + a.y
```

You can also try the trick with global operator and a helper type that implements the different overloads, but I'm not sure if that's going to help: see, for example, [this past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121556/overloading-measure-operator/14122388#14122388).