# Global operator overloading in F#

Tags: f#, operators

I'm starting down the road of defining my own operators for Cartesian products and matrix multiplication.

With matrices and vectors aliased as lists:

```
type Matrix = float list list
type Vector = float list
```

I can write my own initialisation code (and get a Cartesian product into the bargain) by writing

```
let inline (*) X Y =
    X |> List.collect (fun x -> Y |> List.map (fun y -> (x, y)))

let createVector size f = 
    [0..size - 1] |> List.map (fun i -> f i)

let createMatrix rows columns f =
    [0..rows - 1] * [0..columns - 1] |> List.map (fun i j -> f i j)
```

So far so good.  The problem is that my definition of `*` wipes out the normal definition, even though my version is only defined for Lists, which don't have their own multiplication operator.

The documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233204.aspx states that "newly defined operators take precedence over the built-in operators".  However, I wasn't expecting all of the numerical incarnations to be wiped out -- surely static typing would take care of this?

I know it is possible to define a global operator that respects types, because MathNet Numerics uses `*` for matrix multiplication.  I would also like to go down that road, which would require the typing system to prioritise matrix multiplication over the Cartesian product of `Matrix` types (which are themselves lists).

Does anyone know how to do this in F#?

Comment: This might interest you: http://fpish.net/topic/None/59738#comment-74165

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the (non idiomatic) solution:

```
type Mult = Mult with
    static member inline ($) (Mult, v1: 'a list) = fun (v2: 'b list) -> 
        v1 |> List.collect (fun x -> v2 |> List.map (fun y -> (x, y))) : list<'a * 'b>
    static member inline ($) (Mult, v1:'a      ) = fun (v2:'a) -> v1 * v2 :'a

let inline (*) v1 v2 = (Mult $ v1) v2
```

Comment: Dude, that is super-cool.  I ran it in F# interactive, and then did `let prod = [1..3] * ["Hello"; "World"]` and `let x = 2 * 5`.  The results were `[(1, "Hello"); (1, "World"); (2, "Hello"); (2, "World"); (3, "Hello");
   (3, "World")]` and 10 respectively.

Comment: Yes, if you want to know more about this, I did a project which use a refinement of this technique https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl

Comment: Looks very interesting.  As I said to Tomas, I think you might have to pay for this with a pattern-matching operation every time you perform a redefined `*` operation, but even if that is the case, I'm sure the cost is tiny.  I wonder if this can be made to work inside the CUDA monad...

Comment: You pay the cost at compile-time rather than run-time. Which CUDA Monad are you using? Indeed I'm using this technique to define generic monadic code.

Comment: I'm using Alea.cuBase at the moment.  I'd be interested to see your work on monadic code.

Comment: In the last few days I ran into references for FsControl a few times so I finally stated looking at it closely and like what I see. If you had only given it a better name I might have been using it for a few years now. Every time I saw FsControl I would think Windows Form controls and say, I don't need this. I give it vote to have a name change. :)

Comment: @GuyCoder I agree. Control comes from the Haskell libraries that inspired the project but I would be happy to put a better name, I invite you to open an issue suggesting a name change.

Answer (score 12):

The idiomatic solution is to define `Matrix` as a new type and add operators as static members:

```
type Matrix = 
  | MatrixData of float list list
  static member (*) (MatrixData m1, MatrixData m2) = (...)
```

Operators defined using `let` are useful when you know that the definition does not conflict with anything else, or when you're defining the operator locally in a small scope (within a function).

For custom types, it is a good idea to define operators as static members. Another benefit of this approach is that your type will be usable from C# (including the operators).

To do this in your example, I had to change the type definition from type alias (which is not a stand-alone type and so it cannot have its own static members) to a single-case discriminated union, which can have members - but this is probably a good idea anyway.

Comment: Thanks Tomas.  This gives me a nice way to multiply matrices, as the MathNet Numerics package does.  I think I will go down that route, but in the meantime, is there a nice way to redefine the global operator so that it can perform a Cartesian product operation on a `(List<'a>, List<'b>)` pair of arguments?  There is an answer using an intermediate `Mult` class in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121556/overloading-measure-operator?rq=1, but that seems incomplete because I get a type exception when trying to implement it.

Comment: Gustavo gave a really interesting answer.  I've only got one question about it: does his solution mean that the redefined `*` operator performs a pattern match every time it is invoked? Would that have any noticeable effect on large-scale matrix multiplication?

Comment: @RobLyndon No, it does the overloading resolution at compile time, then inlines the code of the function at the calling site. So you don't loose performance.

Comment: Who cares if it is idiomatic - maybe with respect to .NET. I like Gustavo's solution more, it's type safe, it's more elegant, more functional and it afford 'type classes' in F# and that all matter! Maybe F# would deserve better support of this technique in a future version.

Comment: "Who cares if it is idiomatic?" - Well everyone who will have to read, maintain & extend the code...