# F# operator overloading strange behavoir

Tags: f#

Let's say that for some strange reason I want to have this function:

```
let (~-) (str:string) = 42
```

So I can do something like this and get 42 as result:

```
-"test"
val it : int = 42
```

Which is fine. But now when I do:

```
let a = 100
-a
```

I get:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    string    
but here has type
    int
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you define operators using `let`, the new definition *hides* all previous definition of the operator. So in your example, you are hiding the default implementation of the unary minus (which works for numbers) and replacing it with a new operator that only works on strings.

It is not easy to re-define overloaded operators on built-in types. If you need that, it is probably better idea to avoid using operators (just use a function). However, if you want to provide an overloaded operator for a custom type, you can do this by adding operator as a static member:

```
type MinusString(s:string) =
  member x.Value = s
  /// Provide unary minus for MinusString values
  static member (~-) (ms:MinusString) =
    MinusString("-" + ms.Value)

-(MinusString "hi") // Returns "-hi"
```

If you really want to redefine built-in operator like unary minus and make it work on `string`, then there is actually a way to do this using a [trick described in earlier SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682432/global-operator-overloading-in-f). However, I would only use this if you have a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you overwrote the minus operator with one that takes a string and returns an int, then tried to apply it to an int, which it can't do anymore.