# F# Custom Comparison operators for type

Tags: f#

I want to create custom comparison operators for my type (<, >, <=, >=, etc). I have tried:

```
type MyType() =
    static member (>) (left: MyType, right: int) = true


let foo = new MyType();
let bar = foo > 12;
```

and receive the error:

```
The type 'MyType' does not support the 'comparison' constraint. For example, it does not support the 'System.IComparable' interface
```

(Why would a language feature like operator overloading depend on an interface IComparable that comes from a framework? shouldn't the language and the frameworks it use be independent?) So I try:

```
type MyType() =
    interface IComparable
        member self.CompareTo yobj = true
    interface IComparable<int>
        member self.CompareTo yobj = true
    static member (>) (left: MyType, right: int) = true
```

and I get:

```
This expression was expected to have type 'MyType' but here has type 'int'
```

How can I get the expected behavior?

Comment: It's quite common in .NET that language features depend on the types and interfaces in the framework. `Task<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `Nullable<T>`, `IComparable<T>`, `IDisposable`, etc. The list goes on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Reason Why You Get Such An Error

I don't know why `F#` doesn't allow me to write such codes like `C#`.

```
public class MyType  
{
    public int Value {get;set;}

    public static bool operator >(MyType left, int right) 
    {
        return left.Value > right; 
    }

    public static bool operator <(MyType left, int right) 
    {
        return left.Value < right; 
    }
}
```

Even if this type doesn't implement the `IComparable` interface, I could compare it with an `int` as below:

```
t > 2
t < 6
```

It seems that `F#` treat the `(>)` as a `T' -> T' -> bool`:

```
val ( > ): 
   x: 'T (requires comparison )->
   y: 'T (requires comparison )
   -> bool
```

This indicates :

1. The left and right parameters are the same Type.
2. The `T'` requires comparison (`IComparable`)

If I understand it correctly, this is the reason why you get an error like:

> This expression was expected to have type 'MyType' but here has type 'int'

Even if you has implemented the `IComparable` interface, the standard `(>)` requires that the left and the right parameters belong to the same Type.

#### A Walkaround

One walk around is to create a custom function **`(>)`** that accepts a left `MyType` and a right `int` parameters directly:

```
type MyType(info)  = 
    member x.Info : int = info 


let inline (>) (left: MyType) (right: int) = 
    left.Info > right

let inline (<) (left: MyType) (right: int) = 
    left.Info < right


// see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682432/global-operator-overloading-in-f
let inline (>) (left) (right) = 
    match (box left, box right) with
    | (:? MyType as l, :? int as r ) ->
        l.Info > int right
    | (:? IComparable as left', :? IComparable  )->
        let r = left'.CompareTo right
        r > 0
    | _ -> failwith "not support type "

let inline (<) (left) (right) = 
    match (box left, box right) with
    | (:? MyType as l, :? int as r ) ->
        l.Info < int right
    | (:? IComparable as left', :? IComparable  )->
        let r = left'.CompareTo right
        r < 0
    | _ -> failwith "not support type "
```

---

Comment: I was thinking about inline but after I declare those I lose the ability to use the '<' operator on other types. for example let f = 2 > 3 no longer works

Comment: @Mikeb That's why I call it a "walkaround". I would put it into a module so that the default ">" won't be shadowed. Or I'll rename it as "let inline (.>) (left: MyType) (right: int) = " and "let inline (.<) (left: MyType) (right: int) = "

Comment: @Mikeb I find an old answer by [Tomas Petricek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642084/f-operator-overloading-strange-behavoir/22642200#22642200).

Comment: @Mikeb I've updated my answer to make it a better walkaround. Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682432/global-operator-overloading-in-f

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is also a warning emitted at the declaration of `>`:

> The name '(>)' should not be used as a member name. To define comparison semantics for a type, implement the 'System.IComparable' interface. If defining a static member for use from other CLI languages then use the name 'op_GreaterThan' instead.

As itminus' answer shows, this is because `>` is defined on two `'T`s that satisfy the `comparable` constraint.

There is no operator overloading in F# like you can do in C#. This is because operators are functions, and functions cannot be overloaded.

So your choices are either to (a) implement `System.IComparable` as the warning suggests, or (b) apply a workaround with `inline` functions as itminus proposes.