# How does non idiomatic global operator overloading work?

Tags: f#, operator-overloading, operators, overloading

I want to understand the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19687403/2136963) answer

```
type Mult = Mult with
    static member inline ($) (Mult, v1: 'a list) = fun (v2: 'b list) -> 
        v1 |> List.collect (fun x -> v2 |> List.map (fun y -> (x, y))) : list<'a * 'b>
    static member inline ($) (Mult, v1:'a      ) = fun (v2:'a) -> v1 * v2 :'a

let inline (*) v1 v2 = (Mult $ v1) v2
```

F# can resolve overloaded members. (Because it doesn't support currying of members). So, I supposed, it should work for methods as well

But it doesn't:

```
type Mult = Mult with
        static member inline Do (Mult, v1: 'a list) = fun (v2: 'b list) -> 
            v1 |> List.collect (fun x -> v2 |> List.map (fun y -> (x, y))) : list<'a * 'b>
        static member inline Do (Mult, v1:'a      ) = fun (v2:'a) -> v1 * v2 :'a
    let inline (<.>) v1 v2 = (Mult.Do (Mult,v1)) v2
```

> A unique overload for method 'Do' could not be determined based on
>   type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be
>   needed. Candidates: static member Mult.Do : Mult:Mult * v1: ^a -> ( ^a
>   ->  ^a) when  ^a : (static member ( * ) :  ^a *  ^a ->  ^a), static member Mult.Do : Mult:Mult * v1:'a list -> ('b list -> ('a * 'b)
>   list)

The syntax in which operator `$` is defined is confusing. It accepts upper case identifier as first argument of operator and Visual Studio doesn't complain about it

Mult is inferred to be of type mult, but surprisingly this doesn't work:

```
type Mult = Mult with
    static member inline (!!) (mlt:Mult, v1: 'a list) = fun (v2: 'b list) -> 
        v1 |> List.collect (fun x -> v2 |> List.map (fun y -> (x, y))) : list<'a * 'b>
    static member inline (!!) (mlt:Mult, v1:'a      ) = fun (v2:'a) -> v1 * v2 :'a

let inline (<!>) v1 v2 = (Mult !! v1) v2
```

> error FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second example doesn't work because F# doesn't automatically infer static member constraints with methods as it does with operators.

So yes, it's possible but you will have to write the constraints by hand, the compiler will not infer them for you:

```
type Mult = Mult with
    static member inline Do (Mult, v1: 'a list) = fun (v2: 'b list) -> 
        v1 |> List.collect (fun x -> v2 |> List.map (fun y -> (x, y))) : list<'a * 'b>
    static member inline Do (Mult, v1:'a      ) = fun (v2:'a) -> v1 * v2 :'a

let inline impl m v1 v2 = ((^T or ^a) : (static member Do:^T* ^a->(^b-> ^c)) (m,v1)) v2
let inline (<.>) a b = impl Mult a b
```

The upper-case identifier you mentioned is matching a Discriminated Union of only one single case, so it will always succeed and the name of the case is the same name of the type. All this is to shorten just a bit the amount of code since that DU is a dummy type. If it's confusing here's an example with a normal class:

```
type Mult() = class end with
    static member inline ($) (_:Mult, v1: 'a list) = fun (v2: 'b list) -> 
        v1 |> List.collect (fun x -> v2 |> List.map (fun y -> (x, y))) : list<'a * 'b>
    static member inline ($) (_:Mult, v1:'a      ) = fun (v2:'a) -> v1 * v2 :'a

let inline (*) v1 v2 = (Mult() $ v1) v2
```

Your third example doesn't work because `(!!)` is an unary operator, not binary like `($)`

More information about this old technique in [this old blog](http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net/blog/2011/10/05/inlinefun/).